# Should the [signature] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request, tag-synonyms

There are two tags on my radar today: [signature](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/signature) and [digital-signature](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/digital-signature)

**digital-signature** is obvious and clearly defined (though, it still needs a description).

It's **signature** that is ambiguous. [Almost all questions under that tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/signature) use it as a synonym for **digital-signature**. There are only a handful of questions that do not have to do with digital signatures (only some examples included):

**Questions about signatures at the end of emails**

- [*Thunderbird reply break*](https://superuser.com/q/687736/114760)
- [*How to avoid extra white space below paragraph in email signatures*](https://superuser.com/q/820208/114760)

There is already a tag for this type of use: [email-signature](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/email-signature)

**Questions about handwritten signatures in PDF documents**

- [*Okular: how to sign a pdf?*](https://superuser.com/q/813734/114760)
- [*How do I delete a signature in Foxit Reader?*](https://superuser.com/q/973642/114760)

Such questions are rare, and I don't see anyone on *SuperUser* being an expert in "physical signatures", so I think the tag is unnecessary.

Comment: There are only 61 questions tagged with `signature`. I have no problems manually going through them one by one, re-tagging them as needed, but I wanted to double check first, and I'd still need someone to modify the tag as my reputation is lower on SuperUser than on other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe. **There has been no community consensus as of this revision of this answer**; thus there *should not have been* any mass-retagging (not yet, anyway).

That said, there are currently 4 questions tagged [signature](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/signature) (down from 60). They are as follows:

Two about using handwritten signatures in digital documents:

- [How can I add a signature field in a PDF? (not a digital signature)](https://superuser.com/q/485445)
- [How can I sign a PDF document quickly and cheaply?](https://superuser.com/q/137294)

One about using a static image (an “image signature”) as a form of signature analoguous to a handwritten signature:

- [About the security of adding a signature to a PDF file](https://superuser.com/q/515452)

One about the on-filesystem location of signature-related configuration for Microsoft Outlook:

- [Outlook, Config file for users and signatures](https://superuser.com/q/289181)

Comment: "Yes. It should, and I'm on it.". You don't get to decide by yourself to do a mass tag update. "If positive consensus is established, the request will be marked status-planned and the request will show up in the list of approved requests. The tag cleanup may then begin." from http://meta.superuser.com/tags/tag-cleanup-request/info. It's a community decision and has to be then **approved** by a **moderator**

Comment: @DavidPostill My apologies. That…makes a lot of sense, actually. This is the first I've heard of the process for that, though, and [I _have_ done this once in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290151), hence my decision to take it up myself.

Comment: That was on [SO] not [SU], but I expect they have a similar process ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I would expect that the processes would be (very nearly) the same for each site (except maybe differences between very large sites and the others, or public and private-beta sites). Else you just confuse everyone who doesn't keep to just one site…

Comment: Erm. That's what I said ;)

Comment: @BlacklightShining - Your edits were rejected by the network for the reasons David explained.  Wait until the community decides we want to do this.